# Better marker display in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

There are times when we have more than one marker on a live of java in eclipse, for example when we have a warning and a breakpoint and bookmark on a single line.
Eclipse pastes them over each other, and lower items go invisible.
Is there any settings to show them in columns or something like that?

Comment: Good question. But I'm afraid the answer is 'No'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer to this is "NO". I have been facing this issue quite lately since it get's really difficult specially when I have place a break point and there seems to be a suggestion displayed as a bulb spoiling all the fun.

You can probably try some tweaks using: Window->Preferences-> General->  Text Editors-> Annotations. There you can select where the particular feature should appear. Like For Checkstyle waring, you can select whether you want it to appear on Vertical Bar or not. Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)